# Thread periodically calling method without threadpool

Tags: c#, multithreading

I would like to have a thread that executes a method every 500 milliseconds.  But, I want this to occur on a single thread--I don't want it running on a threadpool.  So, System.Timer and System.Threading.Timer are out of the question.  Is there a standard way of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried `Thread.Sleep` with a `while` loop?

Comment: What does it accomplish to do it on the same thread each time?

Comment: What's your main thread doing? Is it in a message pump (in that case, WinForms or WPF) or is it a console app?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: With `Thread.Sleep`, the action wouldn't necessarily occur every 500ms.  So, that wouldn't work for me.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski My main thread has WPF stuff.  But I want a single thread running in the background that does some calculations.

Comment: How long running is this function? Its going to be pretty close, and timers aren't *that* precise (neither is `Sleep` of course).

Comment: @user2588666 why would the action not occur every 500ms? Are you including the time the action takes to perform? You could allow for that in the `Sleep` call..

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Less than 200ms, but it varies.  The problem with `Sleep` is that it makes the interval depend on how long the operation takes

Comment: @stuartd: I wasn't aware you could account for that in the Sleep call.. how?

Comment: @user2588666 time how long your operation takes using the Stopwatch class

Comment: @user2588666: Basically, you just look at the current time, and sleep for however long it takes to get to the next half-second (typically 500 ms - however long you took).

Comment: @stuartd: You're very right--good point. Thank you. But, is there a cleaner way of doing this? It surprises me there isn't an existing Timer class, for instance, that you can run on a single thread.

Comment: @user2588666: There is -- at least if you were using WinForms.  It'd run on the UI thread, though.  The most reliable alternative would be to have an auto-reset event that your calc thread waits on, and have a timer flag it every 500 ms.  Then your task would run on its own thread, but the timer wouldn't have to.

Comment: @user2588666 There is no such thing as a single-threaded timer because the whole point of timers is to *not use a thread all the time*. WinForm timers use windows messages to send a notification to the message queue that a tick occured. The closest thing to what you want would be `Stopwatch` (which btw uses `QueryPerformanceCounter` under the hood).

Comment: Am I the only one wondering why you insist that you must have a persistent thread doing this? I can think of no good reason for that restriction. You could use a [WaitableTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687012(v=vs.85).aspx), which executes the callback on the thread that created the timer. You can do the same thing with the old Timer Queue API. See [CreateTimerQueueTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485(v=vs.85).aspx). I don't know if similar functionality is available with the new Thread Pool API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do a loop like this:

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
while (youStillWantToProcess)
{
    DoYourStuff();

    while (sw.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
        Thread.Yield(); // Or Thread.Sleep(10) for instance if you can afford some inaccuracy

    sw.Restart();
}
```

The [`Thread.Yield`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.yield.aspx) call will tell the OS to schedule a different thread on the CPU for the time being. Your thread will remain in the active thread list though so it'll be able to resume processing quickly.

A similar, possibly better, method is:

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var spinWait = new SpinWait();

while (youStillWantToProcess)
{
    DoYourStuff();

    spinWait.Reset();
    while(sw.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
        spinWait.SpinOnce();

    sw.Restart();
}
```

Take a look at the [`SpinWait`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinwait.aspx) struct. It implements a different logic: it will be very aggressive for short periods of time, and after a tiny while it will start to `Yield`, then `Sleep(0)` and finally `Sleep(1)`:

From the source code:

```
// These constants determine the frequency of yields versus spinning. The
// numbers may seem fairly arbitrary, but were derived with at least some 
// thought in the design document.  I fully expect they will need to change 
// over time as we gain more experience with performance.
internal const int YIELD_THRESHOLD = 10; // When to switch over to a true yield. 
internal const int SLEEP_0_EVERY_HOW_MANY_TIMES = 5; // After how many yields should we Sleep(0)?
internal const int SLEEP_1_EVERY_HOW_MANY_TIMES = 20; // After how many yields should we Sleep(1)?
```

You asked for accuracy so here you have it, but honestly it feels somewhat weird to use spin waits for periods of 500 ms...